# Excel - Hyperlink to file in same directory as xlsx file

Tags: excel, file, hyperlink, directory

I am trying to add a hyperlink to an Excel cell that leads to a file that is on the same directory as the xlsx file. I achieved that with this

```
=HYPERLINK("file.ext")
```

but the cell looks like this

```
file.ext (like link, blue and underlined)
```

and I want to type something else, eg

```
Click here (like link, blue and underlined)
```

I know I can do that with regular hyperlink from "Insert" tab but I want to do it with HYPERLINK function or some other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=HYPERLINK("file.ext","Click here")
```

or

```
=HYPERLINK("file.ext";"Click here")
```

Comment: The correct one is the second one. Thank you, that was what I was looking for because in my case modifying the line from Gary's Student's reply for all sheets and cells which are hundreds is very impractical.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

=HYPERLINK("file:///C:\TestFolder\Book1.xls#Sheet2!B9","click here")

Comment: You must modify the function to use your folder, your file, your sheet, and your cell.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is not working with newer versions of Office. The solution below should work for old and new versions of office. I tested it with Office 2016.

**Multiple cells**

First we get the full directory of the current spread sheet:

B1 `=CELL("filename")`

The cell content for my example is "C:[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1". Note that also the file name and sheet is included. To remove the file name and sheet I used the following code:

C1 `=LEFT(B1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"\","|",LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"\","")))))`

The result is the file directory "C:\". Of course this works also with other directories. In the next cell I entered the target file name:

D1 `Test.txt`

I finished by combining directory and filename into a hyperlink:

E1 `=HYPERLINK(C1&D1)`

**One cell**

It is also possible to combine everything into one cell:

B3 `=HYPERLINK(LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\","|",LEN(CELL("filename"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\","")))))&"Test.txt")`

**Settings**

Depending on your windows settings (list separator) you have to replace all "," with ";" in the code. Furthermore you have to replace "Test.txt" with your target file. The target file has to be in the same directory like the Excel file.

**Source**

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d94e756-2202-4bbc-8795-cc6ba28e8a1b/excel-hyperlinkfile-format-for-a-relative-file?forum=exceldev

Comment: No, `=HYPERLINK("file.ext";"Click here")` continues to be valid in Office 2019. Full paths like `=HYPERLINK("C:\file.ext";"Click here")` are also valid